# Click listener for entire Snakbar layout

Tags: kotlin, snackbar

I have a snackbar and I showing information to users. If user click Snackbar, I want to open an other fragment.

```
private fun showLastUnsuccessfulLoginMessage(message: String) {
    val snackbar =
        Snackbar.make(view!!, message , Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)

    snackbar.view.setSafeOnClickListener {
        Log.wtf("clicked","setSafeOnClickListenerClicked")
    }
    snackbar.view.z=200f
    snackbar.view.translationZ=200f
    snackbar.view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!,R.color.colorWhite))

    val snackbarTextView: TextView = snackbar.view.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text)
    snackbarTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!,R.color.colorBlack))
    snackbarTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_warning_red, 0, 0, 0)
    snackbarTextView.compoundDrawablePadding = resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.space_s)

    val params =
        snackbar.view.layoutParams
    (params as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).gravity = Gravity.TOP
    snackbar.view.layoutParams = params
    snackbar.view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    snackbar.addCallback(object : Snackbar.Callback() {
        override fun onShown(snackbar: Snackbar?) {
            super.onShown(snackbar)
            animateViewFromTop(snackbar!!.view)
        }
    })
    snackbar.show()
    isShowedUnsuccessfulLoginMessage = true

    object : CountDownTimer(8000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}
        override fun onFinish() {
            animateViewToTop(snackbar.view)
        }
    }.start()
}
```

With this code, Snackbar is showing and when I click the snackbar, nothing happened.

```
 snackbar.view.setSafeOnClickListener {
    Log.wtf("clicked","setSafeOnClickListenerClicked")
}
```

This is not working fine.

Comment: Why not add an action button?

Comment: @Sambhav.K Because I want to click anywhere at snackbar. Not spesific section.

Comment: Hmmmm. I will check and let you know